# Archive submission completed with warnings: Configuration Home Partition has fewer than 100 megabytes free

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I've received this warning: "Your configuration home partition has fewer than 100 megabytes free; for best results Apple recommends inceasing the amount of free space.".

[Screenshot of XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH9pa.png)

I would like to know what is the "Home partition" and how can I deal with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partition that your user directory is in.

Or in Terminal:

> cd ~
>   pwd

The result is in you home partition.
Example output:

> /Volumes/User/zaph

In this case the home partition is "User".

Comment: It's weird because I'm not saving to much information, just some photos and plain text. Any idea of how can I deal with this or why it's happening?

Comment: Free-up some space on the home partition. The archiving operation saves the app. How much space is available?

Comment: Ok sorry. Got it. It is not an app-related issue, it's about the free memory available in my computer. Thank you very much.